# Unable to plot dodge barplot with error bar using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a vector `Scissor_select` and a SingleCellExperiment object `seger.sce`.

The vector has names of samples that have categorical values of either "Scissor+ Cells", "Background Cells, "Scissor- Cells".

The SingleCellExperiment object has cell-type information in `seger.sce$FinalCellType` and the unique cell types can be obtained using `unique(seger.sce$FinalCellType)`.

The `names(Scissor_select)` corresponds with `seger.sce$sample_id`.

I want to plot the number of "Scissor+ Cells" and "Scissor- Cells" in each unique cell type.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(zellkonverter)
library(SingleCellExperiment)
library(Scissor)


# Step 1: Match cell type information
matches <- seger.sce$FinalCellType[match(names(Scissor_select), seger.sce$sample_id)]

# Step 2: Subset SingleCellExperiment object
subset.sce <- seger.sce[, names(matches)]

# Step 3: Perform one-hot encoding
encoded.df <- as.data.frame(model.matrix(~ 0 + CellType, data = data.frame(CellType = Scissor_select)))
df <- cbind(matches, encoded.df)

plot.data <- data.frame(
  CellType = factor(unique(df$matches)),
  ScissorPlus = tapply(df$`CellTypeScissor+ cells`, df$matches, sum),
  ScissorMinus = tapply(df$`CellTypeScissor- cells`, df$matches, sum)
)
plot.data.melted <- reshape2::melt(plot.data, id.vars = "CellType")

# Standard deviation
sd <- df %>%
  group_by(matches) %>%
  summarize(SD_Plus = sd(`CellTypeScissor+ cells`),
            SD_Minus = sd(`CellTypeScissor- cells`))

# Dodge barplot
ggplot(plot.data.melted, aes(x = CellType, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_errorbar(data = sd, aes(x = matches, ymin = value - SD_Minus, ymax = value + SD_Plus),
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), width = 0.25) +
  labs(title = "Distribution of Scissor+ and Scissor- Cells in Each Cell Type",
       y = "Cell Count", x = "Cell Type", fill = NULL) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red"), labels = c("Scissor+", "Scissor-")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

Traceback:

```
Error in `geom_errorbar()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'value' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>
Error in `geom_errorbar()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'value' not found
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─base (local) `<fn>`(x)
  2. └─ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  3.   ├─ggplot2::ggplot_build(x)
  4.   └─ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5.     └─ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
  6.       ├─rlang::try_fetch(...)
  7.       │ ├─base::tryCatch(...)
  8.       │ │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
  9.       │ │   └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 10.       │ │     └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 11.       │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 12.       └─ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 13.         └─l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 14.           └─ggplot2 (local) compute_aesthetics(..., self = self)
 15.             └─base::lapply(aesthetics, eval_tidy, data = data, env = env)
 16.               └─rlang (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)
Run rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE) to see 5 hidden frames.
```

Input:

```
> dput(seger.sce$FinalCellType[1:100])
structure(c(14L, 29L, 2L, 27L, 11L, 30L, 30L, 27L, 30L, 20L, 
20L, 30L, 20L, 29L, 20L, 2L, 12L, 30L, 16L, 30L, 19L, 11L, 29L, 
6L, 29L, 20L, 2L, 11L, 6L, 20L, 25L, 6L, 20L, 20L, 17L, 30L, 
3L, 26L, 29L, 29L, 3L, 29L, 29L, 28L, 2L, 20L, 13L, 29L, 20L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 30L, 18L, 24L, 28L, 19L, 16L, 29L, 20L, 14L, 
27L, 2L, 4L, 11L, 2L, 7L, 29L, 29L, 6L, 18L, 15L, 2L, 20L, 14L, 
11L, 29L, 25L, 29L, 29L, 26L, 6L, 21L, 6L, 3L, 20L, 20L, 25L, 
25L, 2L, 27L, 16L, 29L, 14L, 29L, 18L, 2L, 11L, 6L), levels = c("41BB-Hi CD8+ T cell", 
"41BB-Lo CD8+ T cell", "B cell", "CD1C+ DC", "CD16+ Monocyte", 
"CD16- Monocyte", "CLEC9A+ DC", "CXCL10-Hi TAM", "Cycling CD8+ T cell", 
"Cycling TAM", "Effector T-Helper", "Endothelial", "FGFBP2+ NK", 
"FGFBP2- NK", "FOLR2-Hi TAM", "Fibroblast", "GPNMB-Hi TAM", "LowLibSize Macrophage", 
"MX1-Hi CD8+ T cell", "Memory T-Helper", "Misc/Undetermined", 
"MitoHigh CD8+ T cell", "MitoHigh Myeloid", "MitoHigh T-Helper", 
"NKT", "Plasma cell", "T-Reg", "TP1", "TP2", "VSIR-Hi TAM"), class = "factor")

> dput(seger.sce$sample_id[1:100])
c("AAACCTGAGCGTTTAC.p906", "AAACCTGAGTGCAAGC.p906", "AAACCTGTCATCACCC.p906", 
"AAACGGGCAGTTAACC.p906", "AAACGGGGTGCTAGCC.p906", "AAACGGGTCACAAACC.p906", 
"AAAGATGAGCGTTGCC.p906", "AAAGATGCAAGGTTTC.p906", "AAAGATGGTCTCTCTG.p906", 
"AAAGATGTCGCGGATC.p906", "AAAGCAAAGACCTAGG.p906", "AAAGCAAGTAAAGGAG.p906", 
"AAAGTAGAGAGTCTGG.p906", "AAATGCCGTGTGCCTG.p906", "AACACGTAGAGACGAA.p906", 
"AACACGTTCCCATTTA.p906", "AACCATGGTATAATGG.p906", "AACCATGTCGTTGACA.p906", 
"AACCGCGTCATAGCAC.p906", "AACGTTGCAACTGCGC.p906", "AACGTTGTCAGGATCT.p906", 
"AACTCAGAGACTAGAT.p906", "AACTCAGGTATCAGTC.p906", "AACTCAGTCGCTTAGA.p906", 
"AACTCCCAGGCAATTA.p906", "AACTCCCGTGTAAGTA.p906", "AACTCCCTCGTTTAGG.p906", 
"AACTCTTCACAAGTAA.p906", "AACTCTTGTGAGGGAG.p906", "AACTCTTGTTGTGGCC.p906", 
"AACTGGTCACAGTCGC.p906", "AACTTTCAGACAGGCT.p906", "AACTTTCGTCCGCTGA.p906", 
"AACTTTCGTCTGGTCG.p906", "AACTTTCTCCCTAACC.p906", "AACTTTCTCCTATGTT.p906", 
"AAGACCTAGGGTGTGT.p906", "AAGACCTAGTTCGCAT.p906", "AAGACCTGTCTTTCAT.p906", 
"AAGACCTTCGCTTAGA.p906", "AAGACCTTCTAGCACA.p906", "AAGCCGCCAAGCTGAG.p906", 
"AAGCCGCCATACCATG.p906", "AAGGAGCTCTTATCTG.p906", "AAGGCAGTCGGCCGAT.p906", 
"AAGGCAGTCTACCAGA.p906", "AAGGTTCCAGGGTTAG.p906", "AAGGTTCGTAGCGTGA.p906", 
"AAGGTTCGTCAATACC.p906", "AAGGTTCTCTCCAACC.p906", "AAGTCTGCATTCTCAT.p906", 
"AAGTCTGTCGGCGCAT.p906", "AATCCAGCAAGAAGAG.p906", "AATCCAGGTTACGCGC.p906", 
"AATCCAGTCACTTATC.p906", "AATCCAGTCCAAATGC.p906", "AATCCAGTCTCTGCTG.p906", 
"AATCGGTGTTCTCATT.p906", "AATCGGTTCAGCCTAA.p906", "AATCGGTTCTCAACTT.p906", 
"ACACCAATCGAGAGCA.p906", "ACACCCTAGCTGTCTA.p906", "ACACCGGAGCCACGTC.p906", 
"ACACTGACAAGGCTCC.p906", "ACACTGAGTACAGCAG.p906", "ACACTGAGTCATCCCT.p906", 
"ACACTGAGTGTGCGTC.p906", "ACAGCCGCAATCACAC.p906", "ACAGCTATCAGCTCTC.p906", 
"ACATACGAGCCTTGAT.p906", "ACATACGAGCGATATA.p906", "ACATACGCAGGGATTG.p906", 
"ACATACGTCGCTAGCG.p906", "ACATCAGCAGCATACT.p906", "ACATCAGTCGATAGAA.p906", 
"ACATGGTAGATCCGAG.p906", "ACCAGTATCAGTACGT.p906", "ACCCACTCACCGTTGG.p906", 
"ACCGTAAAGGCATGTG.p906", "ACCGTAAAGTGGGATC.p906", "ACCGTAAGTGGCAAAC.p906", 
"ACCGTAAGTTGTACAC.p906", "ACCGTAATCGGTCTAA.p906", "ACCTTTACAGATGGGT.p906", 
"ACCTTTACATCACGTA.p906", "ACCTTTAGTCCCTACT.p906", "ACCTTTATCGCCATAA.p906", 
"ACGAGCCCATGCGCAC.p906", "ACGAGGAAGAACTGTA.p906", "ACGAGGAGTGATGTGG.p906", 
"ACGAGGATCAACTCTT.p906", "ACGATACAGGTAAACT.p906", "ACGATACTCACATGCA.p906", 
"ACGATGTCACATGACT.p906", "ACGCAGCAGTCTTGCA.p906", "ACGCAGCTCTTACCTA.p906", 
"ACGCCAGAGAATAGGG.p906", "ACGCCAGAGCTGAAAT.p906", "ACGCCAGGTAGAGTGC.p906", 
"ACGCCAGGTTTAGGAA.p906")

> Scissor_select[1:100]
AAACCTGAGCGTTTAC.p906 AAACCTGAGTGCAAGC.p906 AAACCTGTCATCACCC.p906 AAACGGGCAGTTAACC.p906 
       Scissor- cells      Background Cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor- cells 
AAACGGGGTGCTAGCC.p906 AAACGGGTCACAAACC.p906 AAAGATGAGCGTTGCC.p906 AAAGATGCAAGGTTTC.p906 
       Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor- cells 
AAAGATGGTCTCTCTG.p906 AAAGATGTCGCGGATC.p906 AAAGCAAAGACCTAGG.p906 AAAGCAAGTAAAGGAG.p906 
       Scissor- cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor- cells 
AAAGTAGAGAGTCTGG.p906 AAATGCCGTGTGCCTG.p906 AACACGTAGAGACGAA.p906 AACACGTTCCCATTTA.p906 
       Scissor+ cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor+ cells 
AACCATGGTATAATGG.p906 AACCATGTCGTTGACA.p906 AACCGCGTCATAGCAC.p906 AACGTTGCAACTGCGC.p906 
       Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells 
AACGTTGTCAGGATCT.p906 AACTCAGAGACTAGAT.p906 AACTCAGGTATCAGTC.p906 AACTCAGTCGCTTAGA.p906 
     Background Cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells 
AACTCCCAGGCAATTA.p906 AACTCCCGTGTAAGTA.p906 AACTCCCTCGTTTAGG.p906 AACTCTTCACAAGTAA.p906 
       Scissor- cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells 
AACTCTTGTGAGGGAG.p906 AACTCTTGTTGTGGCC.p906 AACTGGTCACAGTCGC.p906 AACTTTCAGACAGGCT.p906 
       Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor+ cells 
AACTTTCGTCCGCTGA.p906 AACTTTCGTCTGGTCG.p906 AACTTTCTCCCTAACC.p906 AACTTTCTCCTATGTT.p906 
       Scissor- cells        Scissor+ cells      Background Cells      Background Cells 
AAGACCTAGGGTGTGT.p906 AAGACCTAGTTCGCAT.p906 AAGACCTGTCTTTCAT.p906 AAGACCTTCGCTTAGA.p906 
       Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells 
AAGACCTTCTAGCACA.p906 AAGCCGCCAAGCTGAG.p906 AAGCCGCCATACCATG.p906 AAGGAGCTCTTATCTG.p906 
       Scissor+ cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor- cells 
AAGGCAGTCGGCCGAT.p906 AAGGCAGTCTACCAGA.p906 AAGGTTCCAGGGTTAG.p906 AAGGTTCGTAGCGTGA.p906 
       Scissor- cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells 
AAGGTTCGTCAATACC.p906 AAGGTTCTCTCCAACC.p906 AAGTCTGCATTCTCAT.p906 AAGTCTGTCGGCGCAT.p906 
     Background Cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells      Background Cells 
AATCCAGCAAGAAGAG.p906 AATCCAGGTTACGCGC.p906 AATCCAGTCACTTATC.p906 AATCCAGTCCAAATGC.p906 
       Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells 
AATCCAGTCTCTGCTG.p906 AATCGGTGTTCTCATT.p906 AATCGGTTCAGCCTAA.p906 AATCGGTTCTCAACTT.p906 
       Scissor- cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells 
ACACCAATCGAGAGCA.p906 ACACCCTAGCTGTCTA.p906 ACACCGGAGCCACGTC.p906 ACACTGACAAGGCTCC.p906 
       Scissor+ cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor+ cells 
ACACTGAGTACAGCAG.p906 ACACTGAGTCATCCCT.p906 ACACTGAGTGTGCGTC.p906 ACAGCCGCAATCACAC.p906 
       Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor- cells      Background Cells 
ACAGCTATCAGCTCTC.p906 ACATACGAGCCTTGAT.p906 ACATACGAGCGATATA.p906 ACATACGCAGGGATTG.p906 
       Scissor- cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells 
ACATACGTCGCTAGCG.p906 ACATCAGCAGCATACT.p906 ACATCAGTCGATAGAA.p906 ACATGGTAGATCCGAG.p906 
       Scissor+ cells      Background Cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells 
ACCAGTATCAGTACGT.p906 ACCCACTCACCGTTGG.p906 ACCGTAAAGGCATGTG.p906 ACCGTAAAGTGGGATC.p906 
       Scissor+ cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor+ cells 
ACCGTAAGTGGCAAAC.p906 ACCGTAAGTTGTACAC.p906 ACCGTAATCGGTCTAA.p906 ACCTTTACAGATGGGT.p906 
       Scissor+ cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor+ cells 
ACCTTTACATCACGTA.p906 ACCTTTAGTCCCTACT.p906 ACCTTTATCGCCATAA.p906 ACGAGCCCATGCGCAC.p906 
       Scissor- cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells 
ACGAGGAAGAACTGTA.p906 ACGAGGAGTGATGTGG.p906 ACGAGGATCAACTCTT.p906 ACGATACAGGTAAACT.p906 
       Scissor- cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells 
ACGATACTCACATGCA.p906 ACGATGTCACATGACT.p906 ACGCAGCAGTCTTGCA.p906 ACGCAGCTCTTACCTA.p906 
       Scissor+ cells        Scissor+ cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor+ cells 
ACGCCAGAGAATAGGG.p906 ACGCCAGAGCTGAAAT.p906 ACGCCAGGTAGAGTGC.p906 ACGCCAGGTTTAGGAA.p906 
       Scissor- cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor- cells        Scissor+ cells 
Levels: Scissor+ cells Background Cells Scissor- cells
```

Comment: The most likely issue is that your dataframe `sd` contains no `value` column.